# Opening Bootstrap Modal with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a Bootstrap Modal using the anchor tag. This is my HTML:

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#createModal">create group chat</a>
             <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="createModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
```

When I click on the anchor tag for `create group chat`, the background blacks out but the actual dialog box does not appear. My website has another Bootstrap Modal that load when the page first loads, so I am not sure if this problem is being caused by a naming conflict. This Modal is named `createModal` and the other one I am using is called `myModal`

Comment: Can you provide codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: I included a fiddle. I can't seem to figure out why the formatting is all messed up when the site is displayed in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the modal outside of the li element.

Also, to get the fiddle working, you just need to add the external references to bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah that didn't seem to work. I am not sure what's going on. Everything looks like it should work.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/code4pi/74h2hf0L/

I simply moved the modal div to the bottom of the page, so that its no longer nested within the li